# Is there any documentation on the memory required by scipy.optimize.linprog or other python linear programming function

Tags: scipy, linear-programming

I have a problem with 288000 variables, 6 upper bound constraints, 24 equality constraints, and the parameters are bounded (all must be positive, half of them also have a maximum value).  I'm getting a MemoryError when I call scipy.optimize.linprog with an 8GB virtual machine. Is this expected? Is there any documentation on how much memory this function uses?

I found this paper http://www.mit.edu/~mlubin/pipss.pdf "Parallel distributed-memory simplex for large-scale stochastic LP problems" Miles Lubin · J. A. Julian Hall · Cosmin G. Petra · Mihai Anitescu which surely has some clues. But if I'm setting up my problem wrong in the first place, a new algorithm won't help me.

Comment: I doubt it.  WIth Python/numpy code it is hard to neatly specify memory requirements.  Also I'd have to study the code at: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_linprog.py, to see how much is being done in Python itself, versus being sent off to some compiled library.

Comment: Showing the stacktrace when you get the MemoryError may help.  It should show which operation is creating an array that is too large.  Of course it's the total memory usage that matters, but often one particular one is significantly larger than others.

Comment: There are lot of differences between theory and practice (because it's heavily dependent on your data). So without some knowledge of your data it's hard to answer. I just can give you one negative (personal) remark: ```scipy.linprog``` is one of the worst LP-solvers available. I think it's even using dense-matrices (not 100% sure) internally which can be problematic too. Maybe try something else. I can recommend cvxpy (some overhead for proving convexity; but nice mathematical-looking expressions; can use many diff solvers; default ecos) and to some lesser degree pulp (bringing cbc on windows)

Comment: Just to be more clear: solvers with special-handling of LPs: [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc), [glpk](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) (simplex-based **open-source and free**), [scip](http://scip.zib.de/) (**open-source but not free**), [gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/), [cplex](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), mosek (**commercial**; at least gurobi free for academic work). Solvers for more general problems which can solve LPs [ecos](https://github.com/embotech/ecos), [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) (**open-source and free** / IPM-based)

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate it.  Turns out my linearization of the problems isn't behaving well, so I'll probably have to use a non-linear optimization this time.  I forgot about cvxopt, have used it in the past.

Comment: cvxopt as well as cvxpy is only for convex optimization. I don't know exactly what you mean by ```my linearization is not behaving well``` but if your problem is non-convex, it can't be formulated within cvxopt/cvxpy. Modelling software for nonconvex-optimization is quite limited. Without discrete vars, scipy can do it, besides that there is pyomo for example (including discrete vars; but there are also not much solvers then; e.g. couenne maybe the only free one).